# React Native - using onPress to animate/show/hide a component

Tags: react-native, animation, button, conditional-statements, state

I have this layout:

```
    state = {
        ....
        showFilterArea: false
    }

       ....

       <TouchableOpacity
           style = {styles.submitTouch}
           onPress={() => {
                if(this.showFilterArea) {
                   this.animateHeightDown();
                   this.setState({showFilterArea: false});
                }
                else {
                    this.animateHeightUp();
                    this.setState({showFilterArea: true});
                }
        }}>
            <Text style = {styles.submitText}>FILTER</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>
{this.state.showFilterArea &&
     <Animated.View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', height: 64, transform: [
         // scaleX, scaleY, scale, theres plenty more options you can find online for this.
         { scaleY: this.state.ViewScale } // this would be the result of the animation code below and is just a number.
     ]}}>

     ....

     </Animated.View>
}

....
```

As you can see - I am using the `onPress` prop to try and show an animatable area with the `showFilterArea` conditional - and I am trying to animate the view using a `scaleY` `transform`. When I press the button, everything works as expected, but when I press it again, nothing happens. I am trying to hide/animate the area I showed when the button is pressed a second time.

**UPDATE**

The animations:

```
  animateHeightUp = () => {
    console.log("animateHeight");

    Animated.timing(                    // Animate over time
      this.state.ViewScale,             // The animated value to drive, this would be a new Animated.Value(0) object.
      {
        toValue: 1,                   // Animate the value
        duration: 300,                 // Make it take a while
      }
    ).start();
  }

  animateHeightDown = () => {
    console.log("animateHeight");

    Animated.timing(                    // Animate over time
      this.state.ViewScale,             // The animated value to drive, this would be a new Animated.Value(0) object.
      {
        toValue: 0,                   // Animate the value
        duration: 300,                 // Make it take a while
      }
    ).start();
  }
```

Comment: can you show the code for the animation itself?

Comment: sure one sec ill update my question

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak ok i updated

Comment: Your animation code is fine, `if (this.showFilterArea)` should probably the `if(this.state.showFilterArea)`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak lol wow good catch :)

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak i am noticing the animation only works the first time you hit the button...any idea why?

Comment: make sure that your state is being set, you can pass a callback function to the `start()` call to make sure your `setState` calls are happening after the animation finishes. Also maybe a stretch but if you're using absolute positioning at all make sure you're not covering your button